# How to assign value of a text box to Grails link tag's id?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a textbox on my page that ppl can input numbers, by clicking the button "submit" I want it to be the same as clicking the id in the list, which would redirect to the show page. How can I do that?

```
<g:link action="show" id="<g:javascript>document.getElementById('TextBox').value()</g:javascript>">
   <input type="button" class="bigbuttonstyle" value="Submit" name="Submit" /></div>
</g:link>
```

Above won't work... but that's something i want... please advise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work because when the link tag renders HTML, it uses the ID attribute to build the URL.  I would just use some behavioral JavaScript to bind a click event to your button that would issue a redirect for you.  So using something like jQuery it would look a little like this...

```
<button id='show-btn'>Show</button>

$(function() {
   $('#show-btn').click(function() {
      window.location = '/path/to/show/' + $('#TextBox').val();
   });
});
```

What's nice about this also is that you get to remove inline JavaScript out of your markup which is becoming an anti-pattern.

Comment: Finally... I did it with the <g:form>... It's just a simple function... I think this is the simplest way for that...